# One of my javascript variables is undefined, what do I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

```
$(function(){

    //Location was "set". Perform actions.
    $("#geocodesubmit").click(function(){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $("#map_canvas").show();
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeControl:false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel:false,
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);  
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    draggable:true
            });
         } 
       });

        return false;
    });

    //Marker was dragged. 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"dragend",function(){
            alert('hi');
    });
});
```

As you can see here, when the user clicks on a button, I generate a new Google `map` and a new `marker`. But, the problem is that the marker is not getting binded.

When this page loads, there is an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is undefined`.

I'm guessing it's because marker is not initiated until the button is clicked.  How do I bind the market successfully? (I prefer to load the map after the button is clicked because there are display problems with loading the map on page load and then hiding it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `addListener` call into the `click` handler.

Comment: Why does that mess stuff up?  What do you intend your current code to _do_?  You cannot use a variable before you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(function () {
    var marker;
    //Location was "set". Perform actions.
    $("#geocodesubmit").click(function () {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $("#map_canvas").show();
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    draggable: true
                });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
    //Marker was dragged. 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```